# jquery modal ajax CORS issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, cors, bootstrap-modal

in a table, among other info, I show a tracking number and a link (that opens another window) to the carriers where to check the current status of the shipment.

I would avoid to open a new window and I would show the result in a modal window

but there are CORS issues, and clearly I cannot modify the server(s) since are (clearly) not under my control.

I googled a lot but not found, or not understood if there's a solution

with my poor knowledge I tried to embed an iframe in the modal, but.. if in a simple page, the iframe works.. in the modal it remains a white canvas.

can suggest the path to follow?

thanks!

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM#readme), which uses several common client-side CORS techniques (including a hidden iframe) under a single API.

Comment: Thanks!
I found easyXDM solution.. but it speaks of consumer side and provider side...
that means it requires putting some code on the server..that I cannot do..

or have I not understood?